# Saving Form Data with a ForeignKey Field

Tags: python, django, forms

I want to expand my User Model with a UserProfile model. This UserProfile model includes a ForeignKey Field. In the form, I would like to use a ModelChoiceField to pre-populate this form field.

Whenever I submit the form, I get

```
ValueError at /accounts/register/
Cannot assign "'13'": "UserProfile.course" must be a "Course" instance.
```

Any help would be appreciated!

My Code:

models.py

```
class Course(models.Model):
    course_accid = models.CharField(max_length=10)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.course_accid


class UserProfile(models.Model):
    # This line is required. Links UserProfile to a User model instance.
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)

    website = models.URLField(blank=True)
    picture = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile_images', blank=True)
    course = models.ForeignKey(Course)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.user.username



def user_registered_callback(sender, user, request, **kwargs):
            profile = UserProfile(user = user)
            profile.website = request.POST["website"]
            profile.course = Course.objects.get(pk=request.POST["course"]),
            profile.save()
```

forms.py

```
class RegistrationForm(RegistrationForm):
    course = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Course.objects.all())
    website = forms.URLField()
```

Comment: Can you also show us the view trying to register the user? How do you handle the validation of the form? Also, `class RegistrationForm(RegistrationForm):` doesn't look right.

Comment: I use django-registration to handle it and therefore don't have a view method or class to handle it. RegistrationForm(RegistrationForm) might be an unlucky name choice I haven't noticed now. I amend the RegistrationForm from django-registration with my own adding the custom UserProfile fields for the form renderer. I should have chosen something different.

Answer (score 0):

So, the problem that's occurring is that `course` needs to be set to a `course` instance with a step before, on `forms.py`, before it's a `ModelChoiceField`. The reason why is because querying it, like you're doing with `queryset` is really just searching for a string that matches, not the actual object. 
If you break it up into two steps,

```
class = [some_method_for_getting_a_class_object]
UserProfile.class = class
```

Then it should get rid of that error.

Comment: Thank you! I think I get the gist of why it is not working but I have trouble putting it into action.

Do you mean I should change my forms.py to:

`class RegistrationForm(RegistrationForm):
    course = Course.objects.all()
    course = forms.ModelChoiceField(course)`

As this does not seem to work.

Comment: @kftb Are you getting the same error or a different one?